# Display all values in a list as Text(Animation Nodes)

Tags: animation-nodes, text-object

How to display 'All Values' in a floatlist as separate Text objects in 3D_Viewport?

***TextObjectOutput accepts only single values***

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it with this node setup:

[image]